# ios mapkit, carrier name crash with [LogMessageLogging] 6.1 Unable to retrieve CarrierName

Tags: ios, crash, mkmapview, mapkit

I have added MapKit in my app. I have connected MKmapview to my viewcontroller by IBOUTLET, it runs fine in simulator but it crashes in my device with this

[LogMessageLogging] 6.1 Unable to retrieve CarrierName. CTError: domain-2, code-5, errStr:((os/kern) failure).

I am taking user's location from CLLocationmanager and trying to add annotation in the map. Code is as below:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    MD_myCurrentLocation = coordinate
    setupLocationMarker(coordinate:coordinate)
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}
```

func setupLocationMarker(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

```
    iosMap.removeAnnotations(iosMap.annotations)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
    iosMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = coordinate
    iosMap.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your device's network configuration by going to >> Settings >> General >> Reset >> Reset Network Settings.

Or

import CoreTelephony in AppDelegate

Hope this helps.